# Web Speech API - Speech Recognition does not return alternatives in mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I am trying to implement Web Speech API - Speech Recognition in my web app with the following parameters:

```
    vSearch = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    vSearch.continuous = false;
    vSearch.interimResults = false;
    vSearch.maxAlternatives = 5
    vSearch.lang = 'en-US';
```

This works both in desktop and mobile Chrome except one difference.

SpeechRecognitionAlternative array in the result list usually contains more than one entries in desktop (as expected) but it is always one in mobile and it seems like "vSearch.maxAlternatives = 5" directive is not taken into account.

What I realized on top of that is, if I put the phone in flight mode and try the same thing, I see multiple alternatives are being returned just like the desktop version. So it seems like the API is making an online call as default but fails to pass maxAlternatives option when making that call.

I couldn't find any documentation describing such behavior. That's why I wanted to check if anyone had a similar experience.

Thanks for your help in advance

Here is a minimal reproducible example. To demonstrate the issue run this snippet on desktop and mobile in the same browser.

```js
const vSearch = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
vSearch.continuous = false;
vSearch.interimResults = false;
vSearch.maxAlternatives = 5;
vSearch.lang = "en-US";
vSearch.onresult = (result) => {
    console.log(result) 
}

vSearch.onstart = () => {
document.getElementById("listening").innerHTML = "listening"

}
vSearch.onend = () => {
document.getElementById("listening").innerHTML = "Not listening"

}

function testSpeech(){
    vSearch.start()
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="testSpeech()">Test Speech</button>
        <div id="listening">Not listening</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I am seeing the same issue. Interestingly I am able to get the alternatives to work on iOS in Chrome, but it only seems to work on longer more complex sentences. Short phrases I just get the first result and nothing else.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour on Chrome and Safari in iOS. It might be worth actually raising it with Google or Apple directly as it could be a bug. I'm going to keep looking into it but there is definitely a difference in the results between the two platforms.

It's not ideal but I am solving the issue this causes in my application by creating a class to parse the transcript and convert the tokens to the ones I need. Not ideal and might not work in all situations.